# how do you read in the arguments in separate variables

Tags: bash, shell-script, arguments

Reading in arguments from the command line is pretty easy, `$1 $2 $3`

But! if I want to do a loop that assigns `$1 to $arg1`, `$2 to $arg2`
I don't want to do it by entering `arg1=$1; arg2=$2`,
I want to learn how to handle the single `$`..
How do I do the loop?

to increase the `$arg`, I just add `$arg$nr`  and count up the `$nr`, but how do I do with the `$1`? `$$nr` isn't working..

Comment: See [BashFAQ #6: "How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) (note: in your case, a plain numeric-indexed array would work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The traditional answer, for shells that has arrays, is to use an array:

```bsh
arg=( "$@" )
```

You then have `$1` in `${arg[0]}`, `$2` in `${arg[1]}` etc.

To loop over these, use

```bsh
for a in "${arg[@]}"; do
    # code that uses "$a" goes here
done
```

or, if you still have the data in the list of positional parameters and want to reduce typing,

```bsh
for a do
    # code that uses "$a" goes here
done
```

Note that the quoting is important to protect the data in the original arguments from being split and/or used as globbing patterns.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional answer is to use `eval`.

```
for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++))
do
    eval "arg$i=\${$i}"
done
```

(note that the braces are required as in `bash`, `$10` would be interpreted as `${1}0` instead of `${10}`)